# GCP GKE SMTP port 465 connection reset

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, smtp, google-kubernetes-engine

I've got a Spring Boot Java application that sends emails via SMTP port 465 (non-gmail email). My configuration:

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: ssl0.ovh.net
    port: 465
    username: mailer@external.pl
    password: mailerPassword
```

Locally everything works fine. When I deploy it on GCP Kubernetes cluster I've got a connection reset exception. I've read that GCP recommends some external paid providers but for my solution it's too much of a complication. Additionally I know that port 25 is disabled on GCP -> I've got port 465.

I've tried to simply add a firewall egress rule to enable traffic on every port for my VPC but it also didn't help.

What am I missing? Can anybody help my solve this puzzle?

Additional info:

1. My Java application is served as a simple deployment in k8s. It is exposed through LoadBalancer service on port 80.
2. Making a curl from given managed pod works - I receive a correct 2xx responses from various sites.

Comment: Are you using private GKE cluster?

Comment: What do you mean by **I know that port 25 is disabled on GCP -> I've got port 456.**? You cannot just pick a port, you must use a port that is supported by the mail service. Your question refers to both ports 465 and 456. Edit your question to clearly state the problem.

Comment: 1. I've got a private cluster I think -> simple app deployment + service for accessing it over the network.

Comment: 2. Sorry about the port. I meant 465 -> the port is given by the mail provider. And as I stated earlier it works on localhost, so there seems to be a problem with GCP.

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, e.g. what kind of service you are using.

Comment: If you are using a private cluster, you'll need to setup Cloud NAT in order for your pods to access external addresses:  https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example#gke-setup

Comment: I can make a curl to e.g. https://www.ovh.co.uk/mail/ from given POD with a success response. So that means that NAT is not needed I think.

Comment: The CLI **curl** is an HTTP tool, not an SMTP tool but that does verify that you have public Internet access.

Comment: Enable [firewall logging](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewall-rules-logging) and check if the SMTP packets are being allowed.

Comment: Ok it turned out that my config map port changed from 456 to 465 but I forgot to restart the app. It works like a charm without any NAT configuration or firewall rules :)

Comment: @user1107782 - Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my config map port changed from 456 to 465 but I forgot to restart the app. It works like a charm without any NAT configuration or firewall rules. Thanks for your support.